# Finding the application path after deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-18.04, dokku

I successfully deployed my Rails application `fireworks_app` with Dokku in a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine, and now I would like to add a logrotate file for my Rails logs. What is the path of my application and thus of my log files? There is a `/home/dokku/fireworks_app` folder but this folder contains only the following items:

```
$ ls
CONTAINER.web.1        DOCKER_OPTIONS_RUN  HEAD        URLS      cache        hooks          maintenance   objects
DOCKER_OPTIONS_BUILD   DOKKU_SCALE         IP.web.1    VHOST     config       info           nginx.conf    refs
DOCKER_OPTIONS_DEPLOY  ENV                 PORT.web.1  branches  description  letsencrypt    nginx.conf.d
```

I suppose somewhere in the system there is a folder containing my application with the known Rails file structure, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your rails application you can do something like `Rails.root` to get the path to the root directory of your project.

For instance, if the log files are in `fireworks_app/lib/log/` you could do `Rails.root.join('lib','log','log_file.log')` to get the path to that file.

Comment: `irb(main):002:0> Rails.root`
`=> #<Pathname:/app>`
However /app does dot exist

Comment: Since you are using dokku, your application is running inside an container, which is why you are seeing this /app directory. To access your project's folder, just do `Rails.root.join('fireworks_app','lib','log','log_file.log')`